# Ugly font when compiled application using Qt 6 in Linux

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt6

I compile a simple QT GUI application with Qt 5.15.2 and Qt 6.2.4 in Linux Ubuntu 20.04.4.
As you see in the below figure, the font of the application compiled with Qt 6.2.4 (Right Fig) is bigger and uglier than the program compiled with Qt 5.15.2 (Left Fig).
[image]

**Point:** I do not use the following code:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);
```

or

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

**Point:** Compile sample:

```
g++ -c -pipe -Wno-unused-function -O2 -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DAPP_TARGET
```

Comment: Hmm, it's same font, but with some enhancement (a-la ClearType) going on. Is it same OS install\same GPU\same display? Note, Qt 6 got different render backend from 5th  generation,  Qt 5 app and Qt 6 apps have different system-wide defaults as well.

Comment: Yes, It is same OS, same display, same computer, same C++ compiler.

Comment: Not sure if I would call it ugly, it had changed weight but it's graphically correct font. It's line wight of GUI doesn't match well to the font weight though. Since Qt 6 Qt use OpenFont standard font parameters instead of legacyones.  Weight is one of parameters which now matches standard. SOme members of QFOnt class became deprecated because f that

Comment: I'd say Qt6 version looks better.

Comment: Have you tried setting a font [`QApplication::setFont`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont) explicitly? De gustibus non disputandum est ...